# A user has a different reputation on Meta compared to on Main. Could it be a bug?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

I was curious about how [this user](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/users/25708/dsm) had the necessary 5 points of rep required to [participate in Meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1382/16670) , and indeed their Meta profile is showing that they have a reputation of 13:

[image]

However the user network-wide seems to only have a reputation of 1:

[image]

The only post visible seems to have a net score of 0 and shows a user reputation of 1:

[image]

The reputation of 1 is also shown in the user's "main" profile:

[image]

This contradicts with reputation currently shown on the Meta profile in the first screenshot!

[It does appear that there's a deleted post that was edited by the user](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3/editor?userid=25708) and [another one with an upvoted answer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1/teacher?userid=25708). One edit plus one answer would be enough would put a user's reputation at 13 (which is what we see in the Meta profile), but that reputation appears to have been lost (on the main site) when those posts were deleted, so the main site is displaying a rep of only 1 under the user's recent answer (consistent with the user's main site profile, and the network profile).

I just wanted to check whether or not I'm missing anything before perhaps raising this at Meta.SE (there might be things that higher-rep users can see that I can't).

Comment: Hmmm it looks like the process that syncs main reputation to meta only looks for profiles that have reputation > 1. Which means if they go up, get synced on meta, and then fall back to exactly 1, the system will never update their meta profile with that new value.

Comment: @animuson seems like a bug?

Comment: It seems to be designed that way intentionally to cut down on data transfer. I guess it's just so rare that the design even matters that users have never noticed before. _shrugs_ I wasn't able to figure out how long it's been designed that way, but probably for a while.